Overridden QSqlTableModel flags function not works properly
Im creating a DBMS PyQt app with an SQLite db and I need the records to be editable only by the person who inserted them.
This is the code snippet that manage the permission above:
class CustomSqlTableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSqlTableModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(CustomSqlTableModel, self).flags(index)

        # Check if the index is valid
        if index.isValid():
            # Get the data for the last column
            try:
                inserted_by_index = self.data(self.index(index.row(), self.columnCount()-1))
                if inserted_by_index != utils.getCurrentUser():
                    flags = Qt.ItemFlag.ItemNeverHasChildren | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled
            except:
                print("Err:", self.lastError().text())
        return flags

I would need to understand why when this function is not overridden, everything works perfectly, while when it is active, in my TableView, after inserting a new record, I see this:

When i restart the app, this last line is not present anymore (i think that setData is failing)
NB:
the code that sets the data is:
for columnname, _value in inputFields.items():
     if columnname not in ["config", "src", "exe", "inserted_by"]:
          value = _value.text()
     elif columnname in ["src", "exe"]:
          value = int(_value)
     elif columnname == "inserted_by":
          value = _value
     elif columnname == "config":
          value = _value.currentText()
     
     if not self.model.setData(
         self.model.index(rowCount, self.model.record().indexOf(columnname)),
         value,
         Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole
     ):
         logging.error(
             "[DB] Error in SetData (dv: %s - %s)! Error reported is: %s",
             columnname,
             str(value),
             self.model.lastError().text(),
         )
             returnStatus = False
     else:
         logging.info(
             "[DB] Correctly SetData (dv: %s - %s)", columnname, str(value)
         )

In debug i saw that setData is returning False; consider that it internally calls flags() function and that if inserted_by_index != utils.getCurrentUser() is "" != "<myhostname>" (probably because i'm trying to read the last column of a record that doesn't exist).
Is there someone that could help me?

Assuming that the row/column of the index is correct, the cause is clear: flags() doesn't return the ItemIsEditable flag, and QSqlTableModel automatically ignores setData() in that case, returning False. You could add a simple bool flag as an instance attribute, then set it right before setData() and unset it right after that. Then, in flags() check that flag, if it's set, return the default flags, otherwise follow your alternate approach.
